# C++ ensuring arithmetic result involving literals is 64 bits not 32 bits

Tags: c++

I have encountered issues in the past multiplying literals by one billion, where the result should be 64-bits but was converted to 32 bits due to the presence of literals.

What is the best (safest & simplest) practice when multiplying numbers which will probably exceed 2^32?

I have this equation:

```
const uint64_t x = 1'000'000'000 * 60 * 5;
```

I have opted for:

```
const uint64_t x = static_cast<uint64_t>(1'000'000'000) * 60 * 5;
```

Is this how it should be done? Only one of the multiplicands needs to be cast to 64 bits?

Comment: Append `ULL` to one of the literals.

Comment: Any reason not to use `1000000000ULL`?

Comment: @infixed it's much less readable than `1'000'000'000ULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a suffix on the first literal to promote it to the correct size.  In this case you can use

```
const uint64_t x = 1'000'000'000ull * 60 * 5;
```

to make `1'000'000'000` an `unsigned long long` which is at least 64 bits wide.  This also has the affect of promoting `60` and `5` to be `unsigned long long`'s as well when the multiplication is done.

Comment: I have a additional question:
`const uint64_t x{ 1'000'000'000 * 60 * 5};`
if number in curly races will exceed `uint64`, will compilator raise warning or error?
In my opinion it can be staticly deduced

Comment: @KrzysztofMochocki using `{}` ensures that the code won't compile if this value doesn't fit into a `uint64_t`.

Comment: @KrzysztofMochocki `{ 1'000'000'000 * 60 * 5}` will produce an `int` as that is the type of all of the operands.  This means it will overflow.

Comment: so it should not compile even without `ull` literal?

Comment: @NathanOliver *might overflow. It might also not overflow.

Comment: @KrzysztofMochocki it will compile, it just most likely not give you what you want.

Comment: @KrzysztofMochocki the value of all operands in the curly brackets is `int`, so the result will also be `int`. Converting to `uint64_t` using curly brackets just ensures that this result will fit into whatever type a `uint64_t` is. This **will** compile, because regardless of whether the multiplication overflows, the value fits into a 64-bit integer. `int` is most likely 32-bits if you're using a modern architecture, so this multiplication will probably overflow. The right thing to do is instead `uint64_t{1000000000} * 60 * 5`.